# Why is my Firebase Realtime Database not being created after registering a user with Firestore and matching with their UID?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I was Trying to Create a Register form which Stores the Users Information in FireStore and Realtime database Matched with their UID. When i run the code, the fire-store collection with the Details are being Stored, but nothing Changes or Updates in the Realtime Database

```
 createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, obj.email, obj.password)
          .then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
           set(ref(database, 'patient/' + user.uid), {
          name: obj.name,
          email: obj.email
        })
//
//
```

this is what I Used to Create a Register form and Set a Realtime Database with Uid.
all the Declarations are Correct and there is no error in JS.

```
  import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.1/firebase-database.js";
```

I have the FireStore Working perfectly but the Realtime doesn't, Since there is No Error , I'm not able to Resolve it

Comment: It might help if you debug the problem locally and tell us the result. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: set(ref(database, 'patient/' + user.uid), {
          name: obj.name,
          email: obj.email
        }) This is the only line that doesn't work and that's for storing the Realtime database, it doesn't show any errors or warnings in the console

Comment: Did you check each variable in that line in the debugger? I.e.: what is the value of `user.uid` in the debugger right before you call `ref` with it? What are the values of `obj.name` and `obj.email`?

Comment: The Realtime Database and Firestore are separate products. Creating data in one does not create data in the other. Why are you using both, and which one do you want to store data to? If it is in fact both, please include the code; see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)